# Ubuntu 16.04 logs me out 10~15 seconds after logging in

Tags: drivers, xorg, intel-graphics, xserver, xorg.conf

A little background info, i had issues playing 10bit video on my laptop. Playback was choppy and full of grey pixelation on vlc. so i decided to install intel graphic drivers.

After installing their update tool(v 2.2), i had issues the dependency libmesa not being satisfied(i had a lower version) so i ran `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

then i was able to update to intel graphics drivers successfully. But once i restarted my system. Ubuntu would log me out 10~15 seconds after logging in.

```
$cat .xsessiion-errors

openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to britty at :0
upstart: gnome session (UNITY) main process (3043) terminated with status
---more lines about processes killed by a TERM signal----
```

`$cat /etc/log/Xorg.* | grep "(EE)"`

says

```
(NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
problem parsing the config file
error parsing the config file
no screens found(EE)
server terminated with error (1). closing log file
dbus-core: error connecting to system bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.FIleNotFound (Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory(x20)
AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
FBDEV(0): FBIOPUTCMAP: Invalid Argument(x100)
```

here are the libs the graphics driver installed https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2016q2-intel-graphics-stack-release

I've been at this since yesterday and i've tried everything i've seen on previous questions and ubuntuforums from chown-ing .Xauthority, purging and re-installing xorg and x-server, even writing the default contents of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

All to no avail, please this is my dev laptop. How do fix this problem. I'll happilly provide any other info you need. This is my last hope - i have a lot of important files on this laptop and i spent a lot of time customizing and installing and configuring my dev environment. I'd really prefer not to have to re-install ubuntu.

thanks.